# excel, combinations of two columns is one to one or one to many

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to tell if the combination of two columns is one to many or one to one. Please see the below sample data.

For example, ID1 and ABC1 is unique. **However, for ID3 this maps to ABC3 and ABC4.**

I want the ability to tell if a unique PERSON_NUMBER maps to one or multiple EMPL_ID's. How can I do this in excel?

Data

```
PERSON_NUMBER   EMPL_ID
ID1             ABC1
ID1             ABC1
ID2             ABC2
ID2             ABC2
ID3             ABC3
ID3             ABC4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS():

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>"&B2),"MANY","ONE")
```

[image]